# V-model doesn’t work for dynamically added dropdown

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working in wordpress and using a form plugin. Through that plugin i've made a cascading state/city dropdown. v-model works on the state dropdown as it is already present on page load, however, since the city  element is created after the state dropdown selection, v-model doesn't work for that. How do I make that work?

```
var entriesList = new Vue({

    el: "#vfm-search",

    data: {
        entries: [],
        loading: true,
        nameFilter: '',
        partyFilter: '',
        houseFilter: '',
        stateFilter: '',
        constFilter: '',
        isMember: ''
    },

    created: function () {
        this.fetchData();
    },

    watch: {
        nameFilter: "fetchData",
        partyFilter: "fetchData",
        houseFilter: "fetchData",
        stateFilter: "fetchData",
        constFilter: "fetchData",
        isMember: "fetchData"
    },

    methods: {
        fetchData: function () {

            this.getApi();

        },
        getApi: function (page=1) {

            var self = this;
            this.loading = true; //start loading
            axios.get('/wp-json/frm/v2/views/'+vfmapijs.view_id, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Basic '+ btoa( vfmapijs.apiKey +':x' )
                    },
                    params: {
                        page: page,
                        pname: self.nameFilter,
                        pstate: self.stateFilter,
                        pparty: self.partyFilter,
                        phouse: self.houseFilter,
                        pconst: self.constFilter,  //<------ this doesn't work on the newly created property
                        is_mem: self.isMember
                    }
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    this.loading = false; //stop loading
                    this.entries = response.data.renderedHtml;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.loading = false; //stop loading
                    console.error(error)
                })

        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.$el.addEventListener('click', ev => {

            // detect if a pagination link is clicked
            if( !ev.target.matches('.frm_pagination a') ) return;

            ev.preventDefault();

            let page = ev.target.href.match(/rm-page-16=(\d+)/)[1];

            this.getApi(page);

        })
    }

})
```

Comment: Please paste rest of the code. Btw. `self` is a reserved word in js.

Comment: The rest is just the php file generating variables for the js file. The form html is being generated by the form plugin

Comment: So you dynamically modify the template of already mounted Vue instance?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a typical way of working with Vue but here is what you can do:

In the js:

```
// create custom custom component descriptor
this.entries = {
    template: `<div>${response.data.renderedHtml}</div>`,
    data: /*...*/,
    methods: /*...*/,
}
```

In your template:

```
<!-- where you display the entries -->
<component v-if="entries" :is="entries"></component>
```

Then you should communicate between the parent instance and this component via events or custom `v-model`.